# How to deploy Next.js Serverless App on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, next.js, serverless

I have developed a Next.js App that includes dynamic routes. So I can not use S3 or Amplyfy to deploy the next.js app to AWS. much appreciated if somebody shows me a path to resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: See https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js

Comment: @bertrand-marron have you done this?